# Did Pinky and the Brain ever prove their mousey worth, by taking over the Earth?

Tags: animaniacs, pinky-and-the-brain

> **Pinky:** "Gee, Brain, what do you want to do tonight?"
>
> **The Brain:** "The same thing we do every night, Pinky—try to take over the world!"

Brain's often stated goal was to take over the Earth. Did he ever achieve this in the series, even for a very brief period of time?

Comment: "Are you pondering what I'm pondering, Pinky?" "I think so Brain, but we're already naked." If it wasn't for *Futurama*, this would be the best animated show ever. And even then, it's a tight race. +1 just for asking this question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In fact, they do take over the world, by measure of being the only ones left.

In [It's Only A Paper World](http://www.tv.com/shows/pinky-and-the-brain/its-only-a-paper-world-130267/), when Brain is running short on fresh ideas, he comes up with a plan to create a scale-model replica of the world, using Paper Mache and Chia Grass.  To convince people to move to this new world, leaving the original unoccupied and open for takeover, he offers them free T-shirts.

This plan actually works, and everyone moves to Chia World, leaving Pinky and The Brain technically the rulers of the original world, by dint of no one else being there.

Ending of episode below:

> It ends when, irony of all ironies, the original world is completely destroyed by a meteor, forcing Pinky and The Brian to retreat to their duplicate Chia World, upon which their new world conquest plans take place.

It was a rather silly episode, but we DO get to see a few things The Brain would do if he took over, albeit with no one around to actually rule over besides Pinky.

---

There's also an episode of Freakazoid!, where meddling with the past causes Pinky and The Brain to be rulers of the world in the present as an end-episode gag, but I have no idea what episode that was.

Answer (score 22):

Probably the closest that Brain got to taking over the world was when he became country music superstar Bubba Bo Bob Brain. His hit song, "King of the World," featured Subliminal Mind Control that encouraged people to buy the record and listen to it repeatedly. It was very popular and earned Bubba Bo Bob Brain the Country Tune Award for Best Male Vocalist. His live television special from the Grand Ole Opry was televised worldwide. He did succeed in hypnotizing the entire world; however,

> when it came time to issue his orders, he tells Pinky, who could never remember the name Bubba Bo Bob Brain, to "forget my name, and while you're at it, forget you ever knew me!"  The citizens of the world do exactly what he says, and boo him off the stage.

This short is featured on the VHS classic "[You Will Buy This Video](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/630318264X)," which for some reason I find myself watching 20 times a day.

Comment: I loved that song.

Answer (score -1):

He came really close in the episode "Brain's Song," where he basically made his own "Brian's Song" movie starring himself, moving everyone who watched it into a deep depression, leaving them vulnerable to his hands.  But during his announcement, his body would shake every time he said the word "overlord," making the viewers not take him seriously.

Comment: Welcome to [fantasy.se]! This is a nice find, do you have any evidence you can [edit] in such as quotes or a video clip? Also was "Brian's Song"  meant to be "Brain's Song"?

Answer (score -2):

i think brain took over the world in a viral video in the first episode of their reboot

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you give us any more information than that?  How'd he do it?  How long was he in charge?  Can you add any screenshots?